# Malformed entry in list file 1

Tags: software-center

so i am using ubuntu 22.04 and this is the error message i get:

```
snuc@snuc-NUC:~$ killall snap-store
snap-store: no process found
snuc@snuc-NUC:~$ killall gnome-software
snuc@snuc-NUC:~$ gnome-software
07:26:17:0701 Gs  not handling error failed for action refresh: E: Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_archive_ubuntu_com_ubuntu_kinetic-jammy.list (Component)
E: The list of sources could not be read.

07:26:17:0764 Gs  not handling error failed for action refine: failed to resolve package_ids: E: Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_archive_ubuntu_com_ubuntu_kinetic-jammy.list (Component)
E: The list of sources could not be read.

07:26:17:0766 Gs  Only 0 apps for recent list, hiding
07:26:17:0910 Gs  not handling error failed for action refine: failed to resolve package_ids: E: Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_archive_ubuntu_com_ubuntu_kinetic-jammy.list (Component)
E: The list of sources could not be read.

07:26:17:0910 Gs  failed to get featured apps: no apps to show
07:26:19:0522 Gs  not handling error failed for action refine: failed to resolve package_ids: E: Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_archive_ubuntu_com_ubuntu_kinetic-jammy.list (Component)
E: The list of sources could not be read.

07:28:02:0755 Gs  not GsPlugin error g-io-error-quark:1: Error when getting information for file “/home/snuc/refresh”: No such file or directory
07:28:02:0755 Gs  not GsPlugin error g-io-error-quark:1: Error when getting information for file “/home/snuc/refresh”: No such file or directory
07:28:02:0756 Gs  failed to convert URL to GsApp: no application was created for running url-to-app on plugin=packagekit with dedupe-flags=7 with timeout=60 with search=file:///home/snuc/refresh
07:28:02:0760 Gs  not handling error failed for action file-to-app: Error when getting information for file “/home/snuc/refresh”: No such file or directory
```

can you advise

Comment: A couple of things 1. The title needs to give some clue of what the question is. You need to fix the title. 2. E: Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_archive_ubuntu_com_ubuntu_kinetic- This entry from the sources list needs to be removed.  You say your are using 22.04 but kinetic is 22.10. Mixed entries will as you have experienced cause problems.

Comment: The directory `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` is empty on a new install, meaning someone with `sudo` privileges has added the file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_archive_ubuntu_com_ubuntu_kinetic-jammy.list` which has a 'malformed entry' (ie. error) on line 1..  A error causes file processing to stop; so there maybe more errors beyond line 1 (entry 1 in the message).  We can't view what's in that file; for us to help - you need to provide what's in it.. but the problem is on line 1 of the added file.  That was from a single line in your paste.